# Help with designing a suitable 12-to-5 V voltage converter using an op-amp and a diode

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-regulator, voltage-divider

The question ive been given:

[image]

My work up to now:

[image]

However, I do not know how to calculate the values of R1 and R2 (assuming I am correct up to now). can someone point me in the right direction such as the correct calculation or an example. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: By feeding R3 with the output of the op-amp you are introducing some amount of positive feedback.  Could destabilize your amplifier. Consider using the 12V supply to feed R3 and the diode.  Then just pick a reasonable value for R1 or R2, say 10K, and solve for the other resistor.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @JohnD 12V is unregulated supply as per OP's question. Won't the voltage across the diode vary according to the 12V supply variation ? I agree about the positive feedback though.

Comment: @CuttlefishJoe Is the circuit given to you in the question? Do you have freedom to change the circuit or only the values of the components ?

Comment: @AJN Yes, but the voltage will only vary slightly with the change in current, that’s why they are suggesting the diode as a reference rather than a simple voltage divider.

Comment: The only other information is a graph relating to the diode as in the forward voltage and current, Vf=320mV and If = 1mA. No circuit relating to the power supply was included in the question just the stipulation it must be made of an op-amps and a diode.